# Upgarding MySQL from 5.1 to 5.7, will it create bug for older sides?

Tags: php, mysql, upgrade

I am upgrading my MySQL, which is now 5.1 to 5.7. However, I am wondering if this would create any issue to my older sites, since I read that 5.7 is quite different.

My server is a decade old, and have sites that are using even php 4 codes. There are large sites that can't neither be upgraded as there is no budget for that.

Thanks for sharing your experience, who has upgraded their MySQL version, and may be what thing to do and not to do in this circumstance.

Best.

Comment: [What Is New in MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html)

Comment: it depends on whether your sites use anything that's been deprecated, removed or had its behaviour changed in between versions. I suggest you read the docs for each subsequent version after your current one, to see what's changed, so you know what to expect, and then set up a test instance using 5.7 and test all your DBs/apps against that for any problems, focusing primarily on areas where you know MySQL has altered, plus general regression testing. So...in other words, do a normal migration project that you would do for any software upgrade.